# Firefox: How can I force the cursor in TextBoxes to go to the beginning (like it used to)?

Tags: firefox

Until recently, if you loaded a page with an already-populated textbox -- like [editing an SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290593/162102) -- in Firefox, the cursor was placed at the beginning of the TextBox.

Mozilla apparently considered this to be a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287655) and changed the behavior in 51.0.1 to put the cursor at the end of the text.  How do I restore the old behavior?  I would like a general solution if possible.

I know that Firefox tends to tuck a lot of things away in the `about:config` settings, but I couldn't find any relevant settings via Google or just by browsing around in there -- I found lots of Google hits telling me how to write JavaScript if I want *my* site to behave this way, but didn't find help at the "consumer" end.  Am I going to have to write a userscript, or is there some way built into Firefox to change this setting?

Comment: You could write an extension that uses that Javascript, it will run on every page.